# kubelet_* metrics on EKS, GKE

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm looking to get the kubelet_* metrics from EKS/GKE servers.

neither `metrics-server` or `kube-state-metrics` seem to provide them to prometheus. Information online suggests the metrics are coming from the kubelet itself, but I'm not precisely sure which software piece is usually used to provide those metrics.

I seem to be able to do a --raw query on the node to get the information, but I'd *rather* not write my own exporter for that.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that kubelet exposes `kubelet_*` metrics. By default they're available on port `10250`, path `/metrics`. Additionally, kubelet also has metrics in `/metrics/cadvisor`, `/metrics/resource` and `/metrics/probes` endpoints.

I'm running a self-managed Prometheus deployment and use this config to scrape kubelet metrics:

```
- job_name: 'kubelet'
  scheme: https

  # these are provided by the service account I created for Prometheuse
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node

  relabel_configs:
  # map node labels to prometheus labels
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
```

Comment: This successfully works on GKE. I append it to the 'extraScrapeConfigs' in the Helm chart and voila! Magic.